# cant reproduce pie chart in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

i am reproducing My piechart on jsfiddle here :

I have took the reference from this example :

http://jsfiddle.net/z3fZv/

this is my js code :

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        highOptions1 = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
            renderTo: "container4"
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Test"
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: 16,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function () {
                        var val = 240012;
                        if (val == 0) {
                            return '';
                        }
                        return "2%'";

                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
           name: 'Repairs',
            data: []

    };

         highOptions1.series[0].data = [];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions1);

});

    });
```

somehow it is not reproducing ...Any suggestion would be Helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add jquery file,
missed comma afer renderTo

```
renderTo: 'container4',
type: 'pie'
```

updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xzmK4/4/

Answer (score 2):

Add jquery to your fiddle and you are missing a `,` after the line `renderTo: "container4"`

Change

```
renderTo: "container4"
```

To

```
renderTo: "container4", //<=== Comma missing
```

And select jQuery from the top-left select box.

***[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzmK4/2/)***

Comment: Also, dont need `$(document).ready(function () {` line, because this is the same with `$(function () {`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi It is not an error but yeah you can remove it. You can classify it to be mentioned in a code review.